# How to resolve this error ---> TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of null

Tags: reactjs

I am working on a React project, I got some syntax error like this TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of null. According to me my code is ok but I don't know why this error is showing so someone please help me to resolve this error

This is my code

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import './App.css';

const App = () => {
const initialMessage = useRef(null)

  

  const initialMsg = initialMessage.current.id

  console.log(initialMsg, 'One')



  return (
    <>
      <div id="screen-initial">
        <h1 id="msg" ref={initialMessage}>Loading...</h1>
        <progress id="load-progress" value="0" max="100"></progress>
      </div>

      <div id="screen-start" class="hidden">
        <a href="#" id="start-scan">Start scan</a>
      </div>

      <div id="screen-scanning" class="hidden">
        <video id="camera-feed" playsinline></video>
        <canvas id="camera-feedback"></canvas>
        <p id="camera-guides">
          Point the camera towards front side of a document.
  </p>
      </div>
    </>
  )
}



export default App
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the

```
  const initialMsg = initialMessage.current.id
```

is running before the componenet gets mounted
so you might want to run that after the component gets mounted.

You can use useEffect for that

Answer (score 1):

Before the initial render, the intialMessageis ref is not defined.

You can fix it as follows by putting it inside useEffect as that will run only after the first render:

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import './App.css';

const App = () => {
const initialMessage = useRef(null)


// Use it inside useffect  
React.useEffect(()=>{
  const initialMsg = initialMessage?.current?.id //<== HERE

  console.log(initialMsg, 'One')

},[])



  return (
    <>
      <div id="screen-initial">
        <h1 id="msg" ref={initialMessage}>Loading...</h1>
        <progress id="load-progress" value="0" max="100"></progress>
      </div>

      <div id="screen-start" class="hidden">
        <a href="#" id="start-scan">Start scan</a>
      </div>

      <div id="screen-scanning" class="hidden">
        <video id="camera-feed" playsinline></video>
        <canvas id="camera-feedback"></canvas>
        <p id="camera-guides">
          Point the camera towards front side of a document.
  </p>
      </div>
    </>
  )
}



export default App
```